Why is my function not writing to the firebase?
I am looking to write data into the firebase. But apparently, it is not writing anything when I check Firebase database.
Future<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>> addTimer(String title,
      {String? imageFile}) async {

    final model = TimerModel(
      selfRef: collectionRef.doc(),
      title: title,
      imageFile: imageFile,
    );

    await model.addToFirestore();
    return model.selfRef;
  }


Future<void> addToFirestore() {
      return selfRef.set(toMap());
  } 


  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    debugPrint('Timer called in the toMap function');
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'title': title,
      'imageFile': imageFile,
    };
  }

CollectionRef has been defined for collection 'timers' in the database.

make sure you have properly linked firebase with your flutter project, also create collection first in firestore i.e. timers. if it still doesn't write, debug it to know where the problem really exists
